# How do I deploy multiple virtual environments in Python with a single shell script

Tags: python, bash, python-venv

I'd really appreciate some help launching 2 microservices at the same time (well, roughly the same, can be within a minute of each other) with the same shell script.
I'm deploying a service into production which consists of 2 python microservices and a postgres database, running on Ubuntu 22.03 LTS, using Python 3.10 and Postgres 14.9.

The python component consists of 2 apps:

```
/my_app/do_something/main.py 
/my_app/do_something/requirements.txt
```

and:

```
/my_app/do_something_else/main.py
/my_app/do_something_else/requirements.txt
```

I can manually activate and run both virtual environments with 2 different ssh sessions like so:

```
# ssh to VM with 1st ssh terminal
# cd to /my_app/do_something
# source do_something/activate
(do_something) # python3 main.py

# ssh to VM with 2nd terminal session
# cd to /my_app/do_something_else
# source do_something_else/activate
(do_something_else) # python3 main.py
```

Doing this allows both my applications to run at the same time, basically 2 microservices performing tasks which relate to the same underlying postgres database.

Without building them up into docker, I'd like to build a single shell script which starts both services, each in its dedicated virtual environment as above.

Does anyone know how to do this using a Bourne Again Shell Script?

Comment: You can use `nohup` to start a process via SSH and disconnecting without killing the process. To launch the process in the background, append `&` to the command, and be sure to redirect stdout and stderr to a file or to `/dev/null`, otherwise SSH will wait for them to be closed even if the process is sent to the background. See https://askubuntu.com/a/349275/9287 for more information.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good option. Although I think I actually want to see stdout for a bit at the beginning. I'm using log files to store all my debug info so although I don't need stdout, would have still been nice to look at the output.

Comment: That’s absolutely possible! For example, you can redirect the output to files, launch the jobs detached in the background, and then start *another*, interactive SSH session that runs `tail -f` on the output files. In fact you could even do that in the same SSH session if you put all your invocations into a single script/command that you pass to SSH.

Comment: @KaiChaza   Are you familiar with `tmux` or `screen`? You could spawn each python3 services in their own respective window and then reattach to it later if you desire. If this is a route you would not mind, then I can easily envision a quick bash script to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `do_something` is your script to start and background your service, then just

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh vm1 'cd /my_app/do_something; source do_something/activate; do_something' &
pid1 = $!
ssh vm2 'cd /my_app/do_something; source do_something/activate; do_something' &
pid2 = $!
wait $pid1
wait $pid2
```

should do what you want, and not exit until both ssh commands have completed.

Comment: This will wait until the first process is finished before launching the second one. I’m assuming that this is not what OP wants.

Comment: They said within a minute of each other.  But you are right, so, I will add backgrounding the ssh commands to get them both running as simultaneously as possible.

Comment: So I'm nervous about the 2 wait commands at the end. I wanted to go in, start one process, leave it in the background (I guess that's what "nohup" achieves. I'm gonna go with a lazier approach and just have 2 shell scripts at the home folder, so I'll have do_something.sh and do_something_else.sh sitting in home folder, then open 2 separate terminals. Not very elegant at all but it will cd, open a venv and start main.py for both processes and allow me to still see stdout at the beginning of the processes. Both processes will run forever though.

Comment: You can skip the waits and the script will exit immediately.  If your startups don't exit as soon as the service is started, then you will definitely want to skip them.